# matching un-closed font tags in the same line using regex

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, fonts

i know that regex is not good for parsing html, however this is only a single line string that is imputed to a function. for example, `<font color = "#ff0000"> hello </font>`. now for the regex i would like to have it match if it is correctly closed, i found that doing `^<font(.*?)</font>$` is close but does not handle everything. for example if the input was `<font color = "#ff0000"> hello </div>` it would say that it was incorrect. but if it was `<font color = "#ff0000"> hello </font></font>` it would say that it was correct and would not catch the error. so the question is, what would be a good pattern to check for un-closed font tags on a single string? and i am using python but a JavaScript method would work as well

Comment: The last example has no unclosed `<font>` tag. It has an _extra_ `</font>` tag, that's not the same thing.

Comment: Regular expressions in general are not good for detecting constructs that must be balanced.

Comment: Regex alone has no memory/stack. That's basic comp sci. You need to use a combination of regex search and python "counter variables" to match up open and close stacks. Regex's alone cannot solve your problem. So either use a variable in Python to count the number of open tags and close tags, or just use a real HTML parser.

Comment: yet is it possible to match the extra tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that regex isn't very good for parsing HTML.  Python as an HTML parser http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html that should help with this task.

Comment: im going to still try to work on an advanced regex method, but thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, make the browser fix it; set it as the *innerHTML* of a dummy *Node*, then retrieve the *innerHTML*

```js
function reParse(str) {
    var div = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    return div.innerHTML;
}
reParse('<font color = "#ff0000"> hello </font></font>');
// "<font color="#ff0000"> hello </font>"
reParse('<div><font color = "#ff0000"> hello </div>');
// "<div><font color="#ff0000"> hello </font></div>"
```

Using [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument) prevents resources from being loaded.